# why we use <html> tag although my website runs perfect without <html> tag

Tags: html, tags

I need to know what is the use of `<html>` tag from the beginning of the webpage although website runs perfectly without these `<html>` `</html>` tags.

I knew that doctype is required but why this `<html>` tag is required.

Comment: Because it's an HTML document, no less?

Comment: Have you tried use google before asking?

Comment: By the way, a doctype declaration is not *required* at all. It's only needed if you want to make use of modern HTML features in a standards-compliant way. It's certainly *recommended*, though.

Comment: @Daniel – that depends on how you define "required". The Doctype has been required for at least as long as HTML had a specification as formally defined as an RFC. If you mean "What browsers can recover from" rather then "What the language requires" then you have a point, but writing for a standard is a lot easier then trying to reverse engine all the browsers in the world.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `<html>` tag is not required.

From the DTD:

```
<!ELEMENT HTML O O (%html.content;)    -- document root element -->
```

The two `O`s indicate that the start and end tags (respectively) are optional.

The element, on the other hand, is required (but the language is designed so that browsers can imply it).

Since a DOM consists of a tree of nodes, you have to have one node (the root element) for everything else to hang from, and that is the html element.

It is also a really useful place to stick a `lang` attribute that will apply to the entire document.

Comment: This is true for HTML, but not for XHTML, since a root element is required for any valid XML document.

Comment: The root element is still required for HTML, the tags are just optional. XML doesn't have optional tags though. (The question didn't mention XHTML though, so I didn't bring it up)

Comment: +1 for this answer. I wasn't aware about this "The <html> tag is not required." but will that page can pass w3c validation if page is not having `<html>`?

Comment: Of course. It would be a pretty poor validator if it didn't understand the O in the DTD.

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to use it, it's optional:

> 7.3 The HTML element
>
> > Start tag: optional, End tag: optional

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.3

Answer (score 0):

It is optional tag, but some browsers add it to page, when you are browsing.

Answer (score -1):

generally it works 
but when we have to give some arguments like html vesion
any encryption then these are followed through  tag

Comment: The closest thing we have to a way to specify the HTML version is the Doctype Declaration, which appears at the top of the document before any tags. Encryption on the web is handled on the transport layer, not the document layer, so that isn't impacted by the presence (or lack) of an HTML start tag (and no attributes on the HTML start tag are used for encryption).