# Play a sound in javascript and html

Tags: javascript

I am newbie in HTML and JavaScript
I wrote a script to play sound using JavaScript and HTML

I want to ask what is the use of

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

when i remove it sound doesn't play

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you ever read anything related to `HTML` before trying to work with it?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Introduction#Doctype_and_comments

Answer (score 1):

The `DOCTYPE` declaration tells the browser what version of the HTML (or XHTML) standard your page was written with. If you omit this tag, the browser will take its best guess, which may result in its not correctly rendering the page if its guess is not correct.

The `<html>` tag is what indicates to the web browser that it's about to read an HTML document, as opposed to some other type of file. [It is optional](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3270615/2359271).